# I don't know why my sql is returning a row that is null

Tags: mysql

When the following sql is executed, there is no data in the table, so 0 rows should be returned, but 1 row is returned, and the value of this row is null.

```
SELECT
c.id,
c.title,
c.start_date,
c.end_date,
cu.authority,
c.created_at,
c.updated_at,
CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT((select GROUP_CONCAT(ci.data) from course_infos as ci where ci.course_id = c.id)), "]") as course_infos
from course_user_pivots as cu 
join courses as c on cu.course_id = c.id
where cu.user_id = 6
order by end_date desc
```

I think, this line is causing the issue, I don't know how to return 0 rows, I need help

```
CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT((select GROUP_CONCAT(ci.data) from course_infos as ci where ci.course_id = c.id))
```

Comment: Don't know what the issue here is without having table schemas and data, though I can tell that `GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregation function, and as such, it requires a `GROUP_BY` statement on which it operates, which is not present here.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I don't understand, can you show me a simple example? I'm really sorry.

Comment: Provide table schemas and data first, then provide a description of what your query should retrieve, your code and how the current output differs from the desired output. Then I'll add my answer to this problem. I find it difficult to help you without minimal information.

Comment: If any ci.data is null the result of a concat ofr group concat will be null. Research coalesce